# Как правильно осуществить переключение классов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать переключение класса active на элемент по которому кликнули, а где до того был класс active удалялся.
Нашел рабочий код:

```
<div class="main-nav">
    <a href="#" class="active">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
</div>

var href=$(".main-nav a");
href.click(function () {
    var scrollId = $(this).attr("href");
    change_active($(this));
    //scroll_if_anchor(scrollId);
    return false;
});

function change_active(current) {
    console.log(href);
    href.removeClass("active");
    current.addClass("active");
}
```

Однако, мне надо что бы это было не ссылки, а элементы li:

```
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это должно помочь

```js
$('.main-nav li').on('click',function(){
$('.main-nav li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
background:green;
color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Работает так как надо, огромное вам спасибо!